# Backup/restore subsite with started workflow

Tags: sharepoint

I need to export/import sharepoint subsite to another site collection. But I have started workflow in my site. Is there any way to do this? As I know I cant use export/import command cause they dont allow me to export/import subsite with started workflow. Also I cant use backup/restore commands cause this is subsite.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

To import and export subsite with workflows will not work using the import/export method , if you can move the entire site collection / webapplication then you can use stsadm commands to backup and restore the site collection /webapplication.

You can use this tool
1) http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

2) Or metalogix --> control point tool